# Node.JS, NPM Package - Как запустить локальный сервер коммандой npm start?

Tags: javascript, node.js, сервер, http, npm

Есть веб-страница, лежащая в папке **"webdir"**.
Папка **"webdir"** находится в папке **"server"**.

В папке **"server"** через консоль был создан **package.json** файл (командой `npm init`).
В ту же папку **"server"** был установлен http сервер (командой `npm install http-server`).

Теперь я  могу зайти в консоле в папку **"webdir"** и командой `npm node [директория к файлу bin, в моем случае: (...)/node_modules/http-server/bin]` запустить локальный сервер и открыть мою веб-страницу в браузере по адресу `localhost:8080`

---

Вопрос:
Как сделать так, чтобы, скачав NPM package с веб страницей и сервером, можно было запустить сервер (и увидеть сайт) одной командой - `npm start`?

Должен ли я создать в папке **"server"** JS файл с именем **start.js**, который будет вводить в консоль команду `node (...)/node_modules/http-server/bin` и открывать после этого страницу по адресу `localhost:8080`? Или это следует делать иначе?

Только осваиваю NodeJS и NPM, буду благодарен за разъяснение.

Comment: [npm-start](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/start)

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо, то есть я должен сначала установить http сервер, а потом прописать ту же комманду "node /node_modules/http-server/bin" при создании package.json файла, верно?

Comment: вообще, как именно должна выглядеть команда не могу сказать, но прописать ее надо в какое-то свойство _scripts_

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо!

Comment: Если ты сам разберешься что, куда и как добавь описание как свой ответ

Comment: @Grundy ок, конечно.